# Can I use read_stream permission if my App can be accessed from Facebook and as website?

Tags: facebook, permissions

We’re developing the application for managing news feeds, and we’ve planned to use users’ republications on Facebook for collecting and sorting news from different sources. Our app can be used as Facebook application, as traditional web site, and also can be accessed from other social network websites (vk.com, twitter).
Does it violate the rules of using read_stream (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream) permissions? If so, is it possible to use permission only on Facebook application only? I’m asking because this feature is very crucial for our future development.

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the article you posted, you will most likely not get `read_stream` approved at all for your case:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.